# How do I print output in a certain way

Tags: c#, linq, token, cc

I have written this code using LINQ query

```
 static public void BracesRule(String input)
    {
        //Regex for Braces
        string BracesRegex = @"\{|\}";

        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryofBraces = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            //{"String", StringRegex},
            //{"Integer", IntegerRegex },
            //{"Comment", CommentRegex},
            //{"Keyword", KeywordRegex},
            //{"Datatype", DataTypeRegex },
            //{"Not included in language", WordRegex },
            //{"Identifier", IdentifierRegex },
            //{"Parenthesis", ParenthesisRegex  },
            {"Brace", BracesRegex },
            //{"Square Bracket", ArrayBracketRegex },
            //{"Puncuation Mark", PuncuationRegex },
            //{"Relational Expression", RelationalExpressionRegex },
            //{"Arithmetic Operator", ArthimeticOperatorRegex },
            //{"Whitespace", WhitespaceRegex }
        };
        var matches = dictionaryofBraces.SelectMany(a => Regex.Matches(input, a.Value)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(b =>
                new
                {
                    Index = b.Index,
                    Value = b.Value,
                    Token = a.Key
                }))
        .OrderBy(a => a.Index).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < matches.Count)
            {
                int firstEndPos = (matches[i].Index + matches[i].Value.Length);
                if (firstEndPos > matches[(i + 1)].Index)
                {
                    matches.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }

    }
```

it's output is something like this
    {Index=0, Value= {, Token=Brace}

But I want Output be like
{    BRACE

Comment: Could you elaborate a littble bit more on your problem? Can you supply an example of your input? Which part exactly do you want to change (and how)? The output?

Comment: This is a tokenizer. Lexical Analyser
Input: {}
Output: {Index=0, Value= {, Token=Brace}
             {Index=1, Value= }, Token=Brace}

But I want Output be like
Output:  {     Brace
              }     Brace

Comment: This is your code, but you can't change the output formatting?

Comment: I have tried a lot. i'm still learning LINQ query. So not much into it! Sorry! Could use help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to modify the anonymous object - create the string from the `Key`(=Brace) and the `Value`(={ or }):

```
string input = "ali{}";
//Regex for Braces
string BracesRegex = @"\{|\}";

Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryofBraces = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"Brace", BracesRegex }
};
var matches = dictionaryofBraces.SelectMany(a => Regex.Matches(input, a.Value)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(b => String.Format("{0} {1}", b.Value, a.Key.ToUpper())))
            .OrderBy(a => a).ToList();

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

The output is as desired:

```
{ BRACE
} BRACE
```

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.